# Toad Table Structure Issues

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

Table columns have weird characters

I have this script to generate a table.

p.s. This is an ETL table for incoming data - I know about the bad structure, but cannot change it.

[image]

In Toad, the table structure looks like this (with the weird characters shown):

[image]

And when I click on the data tab, I get the following error:

[image]

Why are all these weird characters showing up?

Answer (score 2):

You can get odd characters in table/column names by quoting them [eg `create table "test one" ("id@" number);` ]
I'd be more concerned about the odd characters in the Histogram column which is system generated. I'd try SQL*Plus and select DUMP(column_name), dump(historgram) from user_tab_columns

That way you may be able to see if the problem is with how TOAD is working, or with the stuff in the database.

Comment: +1 agreed, looks like an issue with TOAD, or perhaps with the way it's connecting to the database

Answer (score 1):

looks like some cut and paste characters.

try cutting the script into notepad, then save it, then cut it back out of notepad and running it in sql plus or the toad edit window.

that should remove funny chars.

(you will probably want to drop that existing table before running the script again )